# Do to add columns and rows to datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a datagrid for my window and trying to add columns to it and then add rows containing data to it. Do you know what I am doing wrong. I know it is something small and simple that I do not understand. Can someone help me? Thanks! I get a stackoverflow exception now.

```
 public partial class Window5 : Window
{
    item items = new item();




    public Window5()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


    }



    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        DataGridTextColumn FirstName = new DataGridTextColumn();
        FirstName.Header = "First Name";
        FirstName.Binding = new Binding("FirstName");
        Datagrid.Columns.Add(FirstName);

        DataGridTextColumn LastName = new DataGridTextColumn();
        LastName.Header = "Last Name";
        LastName.Binding = new Binding("LastName");
        Datagrid.Columns.Add(LastName);

        DataGridTextColumn Department = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Department.Header = "Department";
        Department.Binding = new Binding("Department");
        Datagrid.Columns.Add(Department);

        DataGridTextColumn Time = new DataGridTextColumn();
        Time.Header = "Time";
        Time.Binding = new Binding("Time");
        Datagrid.Columns.Add(Time);

        Datagrid.Items.Add(new item() { FirstName = "Joey", LastName = "Chang", Department = "Education" });



    } 

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    } 
}
public partial class item 
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }


}
```

}

Windows5.xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.Window5"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window5" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <DataGrid x:Name="Datagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" Margin="0,0,0,-3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790"/>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take GenerateItems method out of item class and put it in window5 class. 
Then call the method

Your item class might be referencing a different DataGrid.

Comment: I only have one datagrid.

Comment: Try my suggestion above and if it doesn't work, let me know

Comment: Looks you are right, but I get a stack overflow exception now. I updated the code. Please look.

Comment: This is because your GenerateItems method is calling GenerateItems method. Remove the last line

Comment: Don't make items a partial class. Pass DataGrid as a parameter to your item.GenerateItems method

Comment: Ok, i removed items.GenerateItems(); but how do I add rows to it?

Comment: I believe if you move your generateItems() method to load event, it'll work !

Comment: Why dont you put GenerateItems method as part of Window5 class. Make items a standard class that is not partial. Don't make items inherit Window5 class

Comment: Are you saying pass the datagrid as an argument for the generateitems() method?

Comment: You can do but i think you can simplify it. Make items class non partial. Move contents of GenerateItems method into your window_loaded method

Comment: Ok i updated it. It just shows the grid with the columns but it doesnt add the row.

Comment: Also dont make items class inherit window5. Items class shouldn't know a grid exists. Window5 should know items exist. Thats the theory.

Comment: I did it but it does not show the row only the columns.

Comment: In your xaml, ensure your items binding is correct. Post your datagrid xaml

Comment: Don't you have a wpf. Xaml file? Your windows5.xaml?

Comment: I mean theres more data. If that simple code does not work. Its a brand new window. Then nothing will work.

Comment: Issue is binding. Try doing this... 
            Datagrid.ItemsSource = new List<items>() {new item() { FirstName = "Joey", LastName = "Chang", Department = "Education" });

Comment: And remove Datagrid.items.add etc